Should everything be wrapped in a Mono/Flux as soon as possible?
I am still unfamiliar with spring webflux, but after reading the introduction in the documentation I asked myself why the common pattern is not to wrap everything into a Flux/Mono as soon as possible. For example every Controller method would be implemented like this:
@GetMapping
public Mono<Result> getResult(Request request) {
    return Mono.of(request).flatMap(r -> service.handleRequest(r));
}

Because we want to do as little work as possible on the current thread, but put it all into asynchronous code. So is this the way to go or is something like this already implemented on the framework side?

yes you should leverage the reactor api as soon as possible otherwise the library cant create tasks and events to react to and your code will stay synchronous

This then begs the question what is the “normal” context (outside of the asynchrony code) for exactly? Why not have spring wrap everything in a Flux from the beginning? Or have a AOP advice so everything is async.

You can, by accepting a Mono<Request> request as an input parameter to your controller.
